# GEE - if condition doesn't work properly when using map

Tags: google-earth-engine

This is my work code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e09f8481ae1884c2f98fe70bfde2d7ca

I would like to find to set point value to the closest image (by date) of the collection using `date.difference()` ... I tried many different things, but it fails every time. For debug purposes I have left something like this:

```
var add_values_of_nearest_date = function(feat){
  
  var addProp = function(img, f) {
    
    var newf = ee.Feature(f)
    var geom = newf.geometry()
    var date = img.date()
    var day_diff = ee.Number(date.difference(ee.Date(newf.get('date')),'days')).abs()
    var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 10).get('B5')
    
    ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(day_diff) < ee.Number(newf.get('day_diff')), newf = newf.set(date.format(), ee.Number(day_diff)))
    return newf

  }
  var newfeat = s2col.iterate(addProp, feat)
  return newfeat
};
```

But it seems to totally ignore the `if` statement. Doesn't stop adding a `date` field with `datediff` for every date in the collection:

```
...

        "2022-04-26T11:20:16": 4.5275878125,
        "2022-04-26T11:20:26": 4.5274693402777775,
        "2022-04-26T11:20:30": 4.527421377314814,
        "2022-04-28T11:10:03": 2.534686284722222,
        "2022-04-28T11:10:17": 2.534519247685185,
        "2022-05-01T11:20:01": 0.4722366203703704,
        "2022-05-01T11:20:05": 0.47228299768518517,
        "2022-05-01T11:20:15": 0.47240186342592594,
        "2022-05-01T11:20:19": 0.4724497337962963,
        "2022-05-03T11:10:15": 2.4654553356481483,
        "2022-05-03T11:10:29": 2.465622824074074,
        "2022-05-06T11:20:11": 5.472359386574074,
        "2022-05-06T11:20:15": 5.472405868055556,

...
```

I also tried normal if (the commented part of the code) and still the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ee.Algorithms.If incorrectly.  It *returns* one of two values depending on the conditional.  Both sides are (always) executed, but only one of the values is returned.  You're only supplying one value, and you can't do that kind of test or assignment within the If.  What you want is something on the order of:

```
// Get any existing value.  It's null if there is no value.
result = newf.get(date.format())
// Decide if it needs updated.
result = ee.Algorithms.If(
     ee.Number(day_diff).lt(newf.get('day_diff'),
     day_diff, 
     result)
// Overwrite the value with itself or the new result.
newf.set(date.format(), result)
```

Comment: but why normal if works on value in the commented code then? (`if(value){...}`) ? I don't get it... but will try your solution tomorrow, thank You for your answer - hopefully it will work

Comment: thank You this helped... this is my final working code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7b89f141f49e5d7188587fc5b080f971